# Change text editing background color in NSTableView with dark background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a view-based NSTableView with a dark background color.
Cocoa decided that the text in the textfields, popup buttons etc is better readable if the text is white.

This per se is good, I only have the problem that when I edit text in the text fields, the background color while editing is white with white text.

[image: This is how it looks]

Is there an easy way to get this right (either dark background while editing or dark text while editing) easily or will I need to mess around with the field editor?

**UPDATE**:

After fiddling around a bit more, I found out that setting the text color on ALL cell view text fields to black changes the text color to black when editing. It however does NOT affect the text color displayed in the table view.

I'm not sure if this is a bug but it looks like one to me.

Comment: Tried this today, bug is probably fixed. It works correctly when all the cells have default textcolor  and only the table itself has backgroundcolor black.
Only downside is that the placeholder texts for the cells in IB are still black, so you can't see them anymore. To me this is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to override didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didDeselectRowAtIndexPath to update the text color yourself?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([cell isEditing]) {
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([cell isEditing]) {
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

This code works on iOS platform but should be easily adapt for OSX platform.

Comment: This did not directly fix my issue but it pointed me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @guitarflow what was the right direction in the end? :)